# Elegant and efficient way to modify all elements of std::array

Tags: arrays, c++11, foreach, lambda

I would like to add certain offset to all the data stored in std::array container:

```
std::array<double, 256> data;
ReadData(data);

// apply data offset
const double OFFSET = 0.123;
data += OFFSET;
```

It can be done with e.g. std::for_each and lambda.

```
std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), [=OFFSET](auto& n){ n += OFFSET; });
```

I was wondering if there is a more elegant, less verbose and efficient way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not strictly bound to `std::array` type, you have a choice of other containers that provide overloaded arithmetic operators.

In the standard library there is [`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray), where you can write:

```
std::valarray<double> data(256);
ReadData(data);

data += OFFSET;
```

If you need more operations, like solving systems of linear equations, interpolating, etc, you can use full linear algebra library, like [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/).
Other choices include [boost.ublas](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/), [Blaze](https://bitbucket.org/blaze-lib/blaze), [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/), [MTL4](http://www.simunova.com/de/node/24) etc.

Comment: Definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes just writing the loop is clearer than anything else:

```
for (auto& n : data) n += OFFSET;
```

Comment: This is definitely efficiect but += operator would be IMHO more elegant. Unfortunately std doesn't provide one.

Comment: @tommyk I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: This for loop is probably very efficient but IMHO not elegant as it adds boiler plate code (for loop) to my simple intent which is `data += OFFSET`.

Comment: @tommyk If std::array had an operator += I would intuitively assume that it concatenated arrays, not perform a member-wise +=.

Comment: @tommyk If you want overloaded arithmetic operators, have a look at [`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray).

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there is a **more elegant**, less verbose and efficient way to achieve this.

[`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) is in my opinion more elegant that `std::for_each`, because it's the right tool for the job (`std::for_each` is more generic). It's more verbose than `std::for_each`, don't know how about efficiency:

```
std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), [=OFFSET](const double n){
    return n + OFFSET;
});
```